# How can I convert CSS codes to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

For example, I want these codes

```
.a {color: red; background: black}
.b {color: green; background: white}
.c {color: red; border: silver}
.d {align: center; abc: silver}
```

to convert to an array like this

```
var css = [
    ".a {color: red; background: blck}",
    ".b {color: green; background: white}",
    ".c {color: red; border: silver}",
    ".d {align: center; abc: silver}"
];
```

Is it possible? TIA

Comment: how you are planning to read the css lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var string = `.a {color: red; background: black}.b {color: green; background: white}.c {color: red; border: silver}.d {align: center; abc: silver}`;
var css = [];
string.split('}').map(item => {
    var item2 = item.trim();
    var item3 = (item2 +"}");
    css.push(item3)
});
css.pop(); 
console.log(css);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can "parse" strings in Javascript.  The most advanced would be to use a regular expression, but for simpler tasks you might instead want to use methods like `substr` and `split`.

`split` will let you split a string up, so for instance:

```
".a {color: red; background: blck}".split('{')
```

would result in an array with two parts, the part before "{", and the part after:

```
[".a ", "color: red; background: blck}"]
```

`substr` will instead let you cut off part of a string.  For instance:

```
".a {color: red; background: blck}".substr(4)
```

would skip the first four characters:

```
"color: red; background: blck}"
```

while:

```
".a {color: red; background: blck}".substr(4, 10)
```

would skip the first four, then use the next ten, then skip the rest:

```
"color: red"
```

You can read about these and other string prototype methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 1):

Try following JS:

```js
var cssStr = ".a {color: red; background: black}.b {color: green; background: white}.c {color: red; border: silver}.d {align: center; abc: silver}";

var css = cssStr.split('}').filter(u=> u!="").map(i => i + "}");
console.log(css);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following JS would help,

```
      var cssStr = ".a {color: red; background: black}.b {color: green; background: white}.c {color: red; border: silver}.d {align: center; abc: silver}";

      //Using '.'
      var specialCharacter = "."; 
      var css = cssStr.split(specialCharacter).map(i => specialCharacter + i).filter(i => i!=specialCharacter);

      //Using '}'
      var specialCharacter = "}"; 
      var css = cssStr.split(specialCharacter).map(i => i + specialCharacter).filter(i => i!=specialCharacter);
```

Having filter would avoid the empty or additional value in the final array.

Answer (score 1):

It seems clean using RegEx `/\s(?=\.)/g`:

```js
var style = `.a {color: red; background: black} .b {color: green; background: white} .c {color: red; border: silver} .d {align: center; abc: silver}`;
var res = style.trim().split(/\s(?=\.)/g);
console.log(res);
```